# PhP get first letter as symbol �

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

This problem is the strangest thing I've seen for a while.

I got all pages in UTF-8, adding the `<meta>` as `charset="UTF-8"` in the index page, and even `header()`.

Then I got a page where I add all the link from the top menu in an array, so it's scalable when showing the list.

```
$menu['services'] = "Services";
    $submenu['services']['sendings'] = "International sendings";
    /* And more like this */
```

To display the links:

```
foreach($service as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($submenu[$key])) {
        echo '<li><a href="">'.$value.'</a>
        <ul>';
        foreach($submenu as $keysub => $valuesub) {
            echo '<li><a href="">'.$valuesub.'</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul></li>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<li><a href="">'.$value.'</a></li>';
    }
}
```

This displays me all the menu correctly, except for the very first of all the submenu (just the first one).

```
<li>
    <a href="">Servicios</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">Anternational sending</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Parking service</a>
            </li>
            <!-- and others -->
        </ul>
    </a>
</li>
```

As you can see, there is an "A" instead of and "I". I tried other words, like "Envíos internacionales" (in spanish), and outputs "�nvíos internacionales".

I really don't know why it's doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all your PHP files are saved using UTF-8 without BOM (byte order mark), you can easly check what encoding is currently set and convert files using freeware notepad++. There is "Format" option in main menu, you can either set or convert currently opened file to desired encoding. You can also check for byte order mark using some generic hex editor.

Comment: I'm using Komodo, and only displays "UTF-8" (wich I'm using), it doesn't display "Whitout BOM" as it shows Notepad++. Sure it can be that, but it's strange it only happends with the first one of the submenu, and all the other ones are correctly displayed. I'll try it the soon as I can!

Answer (score 0):

Even though your page is in UTF8, make sure that your DB table is in UTF8 encoding (If the mentioned data is been populated from DB). You could also try using `utf8_encode` or `iconv` .

This may also happen if there exists one or more encoding types are declared in a page

Comment: Data is not taken from DB, thanks. Also tried that from utf8_encode, and think iconv also, gonna try it just in case, when I can I will try that from UFT-8 Without BOM" they recomend. But I just see it strange, that even with a consontant (S, C...) it makes also strange characters/symbols...